# Find file or directory by NTFS id

Tags: windows-7, windows, filesystems, ntfs

Say I receive the following output from `chkdsk`:

`Deleted invalid filename Flatland: A Romance of Many Dimensions (88216) in directory 403737.`

Is there any way to find the name(s) of this directory with the id `403737`, and its current location? *(and a related question, what is the proper name for this "ntfs id" number?)*

Comment: Sounds like an inode number. In POSIX you cannot look up a file by inode number to find the directory entry/entries that point to it. You can only look up a directory entry to find its inode number. MS Windows is likely similar in this respect.

Comment: I would expect chkdsk to report the file reference numbers, but I'd also expect them to be much bigger so I'm not sure.  Try `fsutil file queryfilenamebyid c:\ 403737`

Answer (score 8):

Assuming those are **MFT Record numbers**, you could use a MS tool named `nfi` to dump ntfs information and then a utility like grep or awk (*need to be installed / not native win*) to filter out only results you're interested in.
`nfi` can be downloaded as part of [OEM tools](https://web.archive.org/web/20150329005250/http://support.microsoft.com:80/en-us/kb/253066/en-us)

`nfi c: |awk "/File 72\r/{c=4;{print}next}c-->0"` produces following output on my laptop:

> File 72
>       \WINDOWS\Temp
>       $STANDARD_INFORMATION (resident)
>       $FILE_NAME (resident)
>       $INDEX_ROOT $I30 (resident)

Please be aware that this is 'brute force' linear search so it may take long time to find the entry with high number.

Comment: I'll have to try that. Do you know of any Linux tools that do the same job as `nfi`?

Answer (score 2):

for those who might google this up in the future: I just found out that in Linux, one can do

```
ntfsls -iaR /dev/sdb1
```

*-i* = show inode (i.e., MFT record no.), *-a* = display all (no idea what it does but it can't harm), *-R* = recurse into subdirectories, */dev/sdb1* is the partition device file or an NTFS image file.

This produces a nice long greppable list of files along with their MFT record numbers.

ntfsls is in the ntfsprogs package (atleast on Fedora.)

I wanted to post this under the comment above (where @iqandreas asked specifically about Linux) but the site wouldn't let me

Comment: I haven't tested the command yet, but if it works, there is no need to have this as a comment: it's then a fully fledged answer! :)