# Map contents of NTFS file system

Tags: ntfs

I am seeking a way to view a map/report that shows actual contents of a NTFS formatted partition. This would include indication of positions in the NTFS file system of files that are not deleted and data that has been deleted, to enable me to see (for example) where I can shrink the partition to (in order to utilise the reclaimed space) without comprising the ability to undelete data in the future.

I had high hopes when I came across [NtfsWalker](http://dmitrybrant.com/ntfswalker), and there are a ton of programs out there that show the deleted files, but none are far as I can find that shows essentially full disk usage for the nerds, and not just average users.

Comment: have a look at nfi - I referenced it in this answer: http://superuser.com/questions/491633/find-file-or-directory-by-ntfs-id/491812#491812

Comment: +1 Good start. However, A) This tool would have to be augmented with other code to produce the old-Windows-defrag map-like output I was hoping for (not that I wouldn't be willing to do this. Just hoped there would be an already made solution), B) Are you saying that the MFT always contains reference to every file created on a particular partition with code that respects NTFS standards? If not, this tool will not facilitate a complete solution.

Comment: A) You may try Sleuth kit  (http://www.sleuthkit.org/sleuthkit/) and it's frontend Autopsy (http://www.sleuthkit.org/autopsy/). **Disclaimer**: *I have not used it, but it seem pretty comprehensive.* B) No, although file will be flagged as deleted in MFT, there is no guarantee that the MFT entry will not be discared/reused.